# Insert multiple data from SQLite database to server

Tags: android, sqlite, android-volley

I have an android app, and I am using SQLite to act as a **CART** and I am using volley to send and retrieve data from the database, I have been able to retrieve the data from the SQLite databse and submit it to the server but it only submits 1 value.

But I have been wondering how would I be able to accomplish this if the SQLite Database has multiple rows and I want to submit them all at once to the server.

This is what I have made to submit only 1 data.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_out_page);

        db = new cartDatabase(this);

  Cursor data = db.getCartItems();
        if(data.getCount() == 0){
        }
        else
        {
            data.moveToFirst();
            do{
               // orderid.add(data.getString(0));
                orderName.setText(data.getString(1));
               // orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
               // orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));            
            } while (data.moveToNext());
        }
        data.close();

   btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            order();
            }
        });


    private void order(){
        final String orderN = orderName.getText().toString().trim();
      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_INSERT,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(ORDERNAME,orderN);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who might give me any help or insight on what I should do! :D

Answer (score 0):

On Client Side:
The general idea is that, you can append the data in a string while reading from the database using cursor using a separator.

Now on Server Side:
Parse the data using that separator. Now you have can iterate over the data and place the order.

Comment: Yes sir I got the Client side well, but the Server side explanation I don't kinda get sir haha

Answer (score 0):

you can create a json array of your data retrieving from database and submit it to the server.

Comment: oh okay sir, so the data I am retrieving from the database I will create a json array and then that array submit it to the server sir?

Comment: yes sir, you can covert data to json array to server site. it will help u definetely